# jQuery undefined variable in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, undefined

I've created a jQuery mini script for slider. It's work perfectly in Firefox, Chrome, IE9 but when I hover in IE7, IE8. It's show an alert error (Undefined current_hover_item).

```
$('.nav-item').hover(function(){
        var current_hover_item = $(this).children().attr('rel');
        $('.show-item').hide();
        $(current_hover_item).fadeIn(1000);
        $(this).animate({"width": "+=10px", opacity: 0.6}, 500, function(){
             $(this).animate({"width": "-=10px", opacity: 1}, 500);
        });
}, function(){
        $(current_hover_item).fadeOut(1000);
        return false;
});
```

I tried remove **(var)** keywords but when I'm hover, it won't show everything.
Please help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

`current_hover_item` is undefined in the second function, since the definition in the first function is in a [closure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work).

You need to declare `current_hover_item` in both functions. Or, since you only use the variable once in each function, remove it entirely, like this:

```
$('.nav-item').hover(function(){
        $('.show-item').hide();
        $($(this).children().attr('rel')).fadeIn(1000);
        $(this).animate({"width": "+=10px", opacity: 0.6}, 500, function(){
             $(this).animate({"width": "-=10px", opacity: 1}, 500);
        });
}, function(){
        $($(this).children().attr('rel')).fadeOut(1000);
        return false;
});
```

Or preferably refactor your code.

Comment: Thanks. I've tried your code but in my context, it's doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this problem earlier today.  I fixed it by declaring the variable outside of any jquery functions (including .ready()) and then set it where you need it (where you are currently declaring it).